# Pattern-match empty Fifo.fifo in SML/NJ

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, fifo, smlnj

When I try to write something like

```
fun test Fifo.empty = true
  | test _ = false`
```

I get an error message that says `Error: variable found where constructor is required: Fifo.empty`. I'm really new to SML/NJ. Turns out it has something to do with `Fifo.empty` being a longId, but I haven't figured out how to fix this, except by patching it by passing the `Fifo.isEmpty` as an argument, but that's hardly a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inspect the Fifo module,

```
- open Fifo;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
opening Fifo
  datatype 'a fifo = ...
  exception Dequeue
  val empty : 'a fifo
  (* and so on *)
```

you can see that `Fifo.empty` is an *'a fifo* value. To see how it's made,

```
- Fifo.empty;
val it = Q {front=[],rear=[]} : 'a fifo
```

Unfortunately the `Q` datatype constructor of *'a fifo* is hidden by the module being [opaque](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/modules/sigstruct.htm) (so the `datatype` definition appears as "`...`". When you define a datatype, its constructors (e.g. `Q`) become both *value constructors* and *pattern constructors*, but when you declare values like `Fifo.empty` using such value constructors, they don't also become pattern constructors.

> I haven't figured out how to fix this, except by patching it by passing the `Fifo.isEmpty` as an argument, but that's hardly a solution...

I'm not sure why you would need to pass in `Fifo.isEmpty` as an argument; can't you just refer to `Fifo.isEmpty` in the function body? Perhaps there are dimensions to this problem you're not explaining.

How about the following:

```
fun test queue = Fifo.isEmpty queue
```

Or simply:

```
val test = Fifo.isEmpty
```

Generally, if you feel like passing in a bunch of library functions as arguments, you could instead consider building a higher-order module (functor) that takes another module as argument.

Comment: I really just wanted to avoid checking whether my queue was empty using an if statement and would rather let pattern-matching do its thing for me. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Pattern matching is the way to go when you have access to your data type's constructors. But when the data type is abstract / hidden behind an interface, that's no longer possible. In the Fifo case, this is because its internal representation is a *dequeue* (double-ended) but shouldn't be restricted to this choice; i.e. if you start pattern matching on it, you're creating implementation-specific dependencies.